# Accessing objects member with cout causes segfault

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a binary search tree for practice.  I've added some nodes to this tree towards the bottom however when I want to check on those nodes and their members via cout from the main function I get a segFault error.  However what's odd is that I can assign these members and I don't receive this issue.
If anyone can help me understand why cout causes this then that would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit:
If it helps these segfaults occur even when I don't change the root Value after it's been instantiated.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:

    Node(){
    }

    Node(int someNum){
        data = someNum;
    }
    int data;
    Node *right;
    Node *left;
};

class BinarySearchTree{
    public:

    Node *root;// = new Node();

    BinarySearchTree(int rootValue);
    void insertNode(Node *aNode, int nodeValue);

};

BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(int rootValue){
    if(root != NULL){

        root->data = rootValue;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        }
}

void BinarySearchTree::insertNode(Node *aNode, int nodeValue){
    if(nodeValue<(aNode->data)&&aNode->left==NULL){   //If it's less than and left child doesn't exist
        cout<<"first"<<endl;
        Node *newNode = new Node(nodeValue);         //Create a new node with that value
        aNode->left = newNode;
        }
    else if(nodeValue<(aNode->data)&&aNode->left!=NULL) //If it's less than and left child DOES exist
        {
        cout<<"second"<<endl;
        insertNode(aNode->left, nodeValue);             //Recursively travel to the left
        }
    else if(nodeValue>=(aNode->data)&&aNode->right==NULL){
        cout<<"third"<<endl;
        Node *newNode = new Node(nodeValue);
        aNode->right = newNode;
        }
    else{
        cout<<"fourth"<<endl;
        insertNode(aNode->right, nodeValue);
    }
}

int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree bst(10);
    bst.insertNode(bst.root, 5);
    bst.insertNode(bst.root, 3);
    bst.insertNode(bst.root, 12);
    bst.root->data = 15;            //No segFault

    cout<<"bst.root->data is "<<bst.root->data<<endl;                     //Why does this cause a segFault?  And why does it prevent other stuff from printing out?
    cout<<"bst.root->right is "<<bst.root->right<<endl;     //Why does this cause a segFault?
    cout<<"bst.root->left is "<<bst.root->left<<endl;         //Why does this cause a segFault?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem not reproduced. Could you provide more elements as debugger outputs showing SegFault ? My outputs are "`first  \n 
second \n 
first \n 
third \n 
bst.root->data is 15 \n 
bst.root->right is 1c833a0 \n 
bst.root->left is 1c83380`"

Answer (score 0):

The first glaring error is this in your `BinarySearchTree` constructor:

```
 if(root != NULL){
   root->data = rootValue;  // undefined behavior
```

`root` is uninitialized, so it contains any garbage value.  Then when you use that garbage value (`root->data`), your program has gone into the land of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I decided to change `Node *root;` to `Node *root = new Node();` after reading your comment. I understand that we're supposed to minimize the use of the new keyword. This doesn't seem like a situation in which we'd have to use the heap however. How can I initialize this while still using the stack?

Comment: My comment just states that you are using an uninitialized pointer.  All pointers must be pointing somewhere valid before you attempt to dereference them or use them.  Unless you make `root` just `Node root;` instead of a pointer, then you have no choice but to allocate one dynamically